# Развитие или деградация?

Tags: лингвистика

Сейчас повсеместно идут споры о появлении в русском языке новых слов и выражений, которых не было раньше или которые раньше считались жаргонными. Все эти "в разы", "албанский", смайлики в тексте и т.д. (это то, что навскидку в голову пришло) и всевозможные новые привила, вроде "кофе - оно". Есть мнение, что это нормально, и язык должен меняться и развиваться. Но, на мой взгляд, он должен развиваться, а не деградировать. В чем вообще заключается развитие языка и можно ли все вышеперечисленное считать таковым?

Comment: Я не сомневаюсь, что:

1) "кофей" - "он", а "кофе" - "оно",

2) "постеля" - "она", и "постель" - "она".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вопрос, конечно, не для быстрого и  короткого ответа. Язык, особенное его лексика, следует за изменениями в обществе. Наше общество за последние 25 лет стало другим. Во-первых, рухнул так называемый железный занавес, мы стали ездить по миру, общаться, видеть и узнавать, как живут в других странах . Это условие и причина заимствований. Во- вторых, перемены в  экономической ситуации, развитие цифровых технологий (компьютеры, интернет и т.д.)также вызвали вал новых слов, преимущественно заимствованных. В-третьих. сейчас уже практически никто не говорит по бумажке: и политики, и ведущие на телевидении и радио демонстрируют нам неподготовленную речь. Отсюда влияние разговорной речи и ,как следствие, более частотное нарушение норм в публичной речи, той, которая раньше была образцовой.В-четвертых, открытость и "демократизация" общества привели к потоку жаргонных слов на телевидение и страницы СМИ.Тема большая и интересная. Что отсеется. что останется - покажет время.  Я, например, считаю многие заимствования неоправданными, надуманными, особенное в речи политиков, когда, для того чтобы казаться умнее и образованнее, берется английское слово и добавляются русские морфемы. Например,Клинер - уборщица (от англ to clean- чистить). Таких слов. по подсчетам, в день обрушивается на наши головы до 50!

Answer (score 3):

Ваши примеры, я бы сказала - разного порядка. Одно дела "олбанский", а другое - смайлик. Это не изменение языка, а попытка внести в письменную речь интонации, которые есть в устной. Что касается *кофе* - лично мне больше нравится говорить "он", но я понимаю, что это просто форма моего снобизма.

Думаю, ответ на этот вопрос требует вдумчивого, научного исследования. И главная ошибка, в которую, как мне кажется, впадают "страдатели за язык" - в том, что они сравнивают язык образованной части общества, который только и "слышен" нам, скажем, из 19 века, с народной языковой стихией, которая вырвалась на поверхность с развитием средств связи. Думаю, что простые крестьяне и рабочие и раньше говорили просто и даже примитивно. С другой стороны, сегодня сохраняется слой людей, держащих марку в речи. Именно из их уст мы часто слышим тревогу за язык. 
Вот только оценить, не истончается ли этот слой, трудно в одиночку, не проводя серьезного исследования.

ЗЫ (извините за жаргонизм. Это значит PS :-)). Как-то после заседания философского кружка мы пили чай, беседовали о том - о сем, и один из участников (священник) сказал: "Вы что сидите, как опущенный?" И тут же поправился: "Как в воду опущенный". Эта оговорка вызвала общий смех: вся (весьма культурная) аудитория поняла, почему он поспешил исправить свои слова. Тюремный жаргон оказался понятен всем поголовно.

Answer (score 1):

Тема слишком объемная для однозначного ответа.  Если в двух словах, то во-первых, надо разделять изменения языка, изменения орфографии (и пунктуации) и приёмы графического оформления. А во-вторых, язык меняться, конечно, должен, но не так примитивно. Хотя обычно спасает языковый консерватизм. Изменения в языке идут очень медленно и обычно отстают от изменений, скажем, реалий исторических и социальных, которые эти языковые изменения и порождают. И эта медлительность языка - благо. Иначе язык давно бы перестал быть понятен менее "передовой" части общества.

Answer (score 1):

Реформа русского языка, выполненная А. С. Пушкиным (почти в одиночку!) в первой четверти 19-го века, - разве это не развитие языка по сравнению с предыдущим уровнем его? О какой деградации может идти речь, [[@solariss](/users/2653/solariss)](/users/2653/solariss)? Хотя ... если смотреть в исторической перспективе, всё рождённое, проходя период расцвета, заканчивается смертью. Это утверждение как будто противоречит пункту 1 [[[[@София](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F), основанному на бесконечном, по спирали, диалектическом приближении к Истине, но История - Дама бескомпромиссная, а Практика - в любом случае - Палач теории... Тюремный жаргон, по [[@DocentI](/users/508/docenti)](/users/508/docenti), - это угасание языка, хотя зэки - тоже люди, правда, опущенные. В общем, прав [[@Галактион](/users/996/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD)](/users/996/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD): хоть "постеля", хоть "постель" - всё "отселе" и "досель". Что хотела сказать [[[[@София](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F) пунктом 3: "за здравие" или "за упокой", я не понял.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то лингвистам известен очень интересный, но малоизвестный факт: все языки деградируют на протяжении тысячелетий! Например еще недавно в русском языке было 5 склонений, не говоря о том, что букв в алфавите было намного больше... А латынь, которая по структуре была весьма близка к русскому, превратилась в итальянский (ее прямой наследник), который начисто утратил склонения... 
И, на сколько мне известно, это происходит со всеми языками, запечатленными в письменности. И тут возникает интересный вопрос о том, как языки вообще могли возникнуть, если все известное время они деградируют?
А то, что происходит в наши смутные времена глобализации, то это немного другое...

Comment: Вы считате, что утрата архаических типов склонений и прочих рудиментов - признак деградации?  
Типа утрата хвоста приматами, на их пути становления людьми - признак их вырождения?  
ну-ну...

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно предположить, что язык развивается по законам диалектики, то есть по спирали. Это можно обозначить примерно так: 1)примитивное состояние; 2) усложнение, 3) упрощение ненужных сложностей, достижение определенного уровня. Далее виток развития повторяется.
2. Этот процесс  можно наблюдать на примере словоизменительной системы существительных. Раньше было несколько склонений, а сейчас их количество сокращено до трех. Но это развитие, а не деградация. Большое количество склонений определялось несовершенством фонетической системы (тип склонения зависел от основы), а в настоящее  время он соотносится с родом существительных. Большое количество склонений нам просто ни к чему - это ненужная сложность.
3. Уровень развития языка можно определить по возможности точно выразить большой семантический объем, для чего нужно совершенное развитие всех структур - лексики, грамматики, словообразования.